Godfather II - the attempted hit on Pentangeli
Two questions:

Why do the lie to Pentangeli, saying that Michael ordered the hit of they intended to actually kill him? It's pointless except in terms of plotting (i.e. It means that Pentangeli, having survived through luck, thinks Michael did order the hit)

Why do they try to kill him anyway? It just creates a problem between Michael and Roth.



If you have two questions, you should ask them as two questions

Because they are closely related?
As an aside, do you do bar mitzvahs and weddings?

Just read it. Thanks. Tbh I think my explanation makes more sense, and answers some of the questions raised there.

@TomMelly Then maybe post your explanation as an answer on the other question instead?

Well, after a bath, I think I've worked out the answers.

At least one of the hitmen doesn't know the truth (that Roth ordered the hit on Michael, not Pentangeli), and this is either said for their benefit or said by them - i.e. a sort of "the Lannisters send their regards" shtick.

Because Roth believes that Michael thinks Pentangeli arranged the attempted assassination, he wants P out of the way in case he's able to establish his innocence. Hence it being important that someone implies that it's being done for Michael's benefit, since either the barman or one of the hitmen may inform Michael of what happened and what was said.


